# SignalR. Why is groups sent to clients?

Tags: protocols, signalr

Im looking at SignalR traffic between a client and a server.

Why is information about joined groups sent to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR sends groups down to the client for 2 reasons.

1. When a client reconnects it may no longer be a part of the groups it once was in, therefore it needs to rejoin them.
2. In scale-out situations the currently connected to server needs to know what groups the client was in.

Hope this helps!